# How do I find all UTF-8 strings in a .rda file?

Tags: r

I am preparing my R package for rerelease. When I check my R package's current CRAN check results I get a note from `r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang` and `r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-gcc` saying

```
checking data for non-ASCII characters ... NOTE
  Note: found 399 marked UTF-8 strings
```

My package is essentially a data package and has multiple .rda files. I am assuming one of these contains non-ASCII characters. Is there a way I can search through just .rda files for non-ASCII characters?

I tried using find in files, then searching for `[^\x00-\x7F]` and selecting regular expression. I also selected "custom filter" under the "search these files" dropdown list and then entered *.rda but it says nothing is found. As a note, all other checks run fine with no notes about non-ASCII characters.